# Is it possible to make a regex that accepts ANY substring

Tags: javascript, java, regex, parsing

I'm somewhat new to regex. I understand most of the basics but what I'm trying to do is beyond my knowledge, and may not even be possible.

I'm trying to make a regex in JavaScript that can match a series of function calls in the following pattern.

`Name.Name(Params).Name(Params)`

The names could be any standard java function name. I understand how do to this part. The params though can be different number of parameters (Currently only 0-2)

My biggest issue however is that params could potentially take ANY string with either a single or double quotation mark, or variable names. I have added some examples below as I need all of these to work with my regular expression (if Possible).

Examples:

`Func.Foo().Bar()`

`Foo.Bar('foo', bar).Foobar()`

`Foo.Bar("foo", "bar").bar(')')`

`Foo.Bar('/"foo/"').bar("foo(bar/")")`

My main concern here is I cant just look for a opening and parentheses or even 2 quotation marks. 
Is it possible to use a regex so that I can parse the function call and parameters out?

Comment: Can you provide us some code?

Comment: No. regex is not a good tool to recognize and and parse nested parenthesized expressions.

Comment: My first question is Why. Whatever your trying to do you're probably better off working with an AST parser. i found [this](http://javaparser.org/) in a google search

Comment: I cannot provide code as its for an employer who requested that I do not.  I will look into the AST parser though as I do believe that you are correct that I should pursue something other than regex for this.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to the Question in the title is yes, you can build a regex that matches any substring. But unfortunately that is not what you want. If you allow arbitrary substrings your regex will either match many cases you dont want to match or it will become extremely complex (see the email regex for an example).

What you want is a tokenizer!(https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-math-expression-tokenizer-using-javascript-3638d4e5fbe9)

Edit: for the solutions in the comments: the ast parser is for java, the author wants to use javascript.

Comment: Yeah I looked at the email regex before making this post. But you are probably right that regex is not the direction I should go for it.

Comment: If you feel that the question has been answered please accept the answer. Thank you.